# How to retrieve field from any table in a flatbuffer schema

Tags: c#, flatbuffers

maybe this is a trivial question but...
I have a flatbuffer schema which defines some messages (tables).

```
enum EMessages : int
{
  E_MSG_EVENT_SYSTEM_INFO  = 0x8000,
  E_MSG_EVENT_SYSTEM_ERROR = 0x8001,
}


table  TMsgHeader
{
  sessionRef    : int;
  transactionId : int;
  status        : EStatus;
  source_id     : string;
}

table  MSG_EVENT_SYSTEM_INFO
{
  opcode        : EMessages  = E_MSG_EVENT_SYSTEM_INFO;
  header        : TMsgHeader;
  protocol_ver  : int = 100;
}

table  MSG_EVENT_SYSTEM_ERROR
{
  opcode        : EMessages  = E_MSG_EVENT_SYSTEM_ERROR;
  header        : TMsgHeader;
  error_no      : int;
  error_desc    : string;
}
```

On receiving side, I need a way to retrieve the OpCode field to know which message is (to deserialize it). 
Cause, since every message has different size, the OpCode field is never in the same position on the binary buffer sent.

Is there some "best practice" applied to FlatBuffer?

I wanna avoid to encapsulate the FB payload into another message appending the OpCode.

Comment: This is binary type data.  You need to read dynamically.  First read the opcode as 4 bytes. then read data based on the opcode.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, my problem is just that: read the 4-bytes opcode from the binary buffer. Since every tables has different size, FB serialize them in different ways, and the 4-byte opcode is never in the same position in the buffer over-the-wire. So, on the receiving side I need to find a way to know "where" is the opcode into the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best of using the built-in union feature, something like:

```
union Message { Info, Error }
table Info { protocol_ver:int }
table Error { error_no:int; error_string:string }
table Header { msg:Message; /* all other header fields go here */ }
root_type Header
```

See the documentation on how to serialize and read unions. What was previously `opcode` is now `msg_type`.